# sql testing for invalid input when submitting two values both of which are individually valid, using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to validate a form's input.  The issue is that the inputs may be individually valid, but unrelated.

For example, I have a form with fields for a 'course_id' and an 'instructor' that a student submits to reserve a space.  How do I test for the invalid case of the input being (1) a course_id offered by instructor A and (2) the form specifying instructor B.  Only instructor A teaches this particular course.  (The course_id, instructor_a, and instructor_b are all in the database.  But the course and instructor submitted by the student are unrelated, i.e., don't match.)

Here's what I've tried:

```
  active_course = @class.course_id
  active_instructor = @class.instructor_name
```

And the test (which doesn't work):

```
Class.where(:course_id == active_course).select("instructor_id")
!= Class.where(:instructor_name == active_instructor).select("instructor_id")
```

So, what I'm trying to do, is identify the instructor of the course and determine if that instructor_id is teaching the course. The first half of my test seems to work.  It's the relationship between the instructor's name and his / her id that I'm having difficulty with.  (Unfortunately, I can't just change the input field to the instructor's id.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Keep a drop down menu that displays the instructors name and keep the instructor_id as its value then that would make your case a lot easier.

Comment: You would like to return an error if the two are not related? (Instructor doesn't teach that course)

Comment: Can you create associations between instructors and the courses they teach in the rails model?

Comment: Q1- Yes, I'd like an error if unrelated

Comment: Q2 - That relationship already exists.  The problem is that the values are both valid, but related to one another.  How do I test for an error, specifically valid class, valid instructor, but the instructor doesn't teach the course being requested.  I.e., the student filled out the form incorrectly.